# Ошибка POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php

Есть форма для отправки данных на почту, где при нажатии на кнопку send должна происходить отправка ее на почту. Добавил все ее файлы на хостинг,но при тесте консоль стала выдавать ошибку  POST /ссылка на файл php 500 (Internal Server Error) и рядом указана строка кода fetch js. В чем ошибка и как ее решить?
Ссылка на форму: http://w77864gu.beget.tech/form.html
Код fetch js

```js
let formData = new FormData(form); //Получение всех данных полей с помощью formData
formData.append("image", formImage.files[0]); // Добавление в переменную formData картинок (images)

if (error === 0) {
  form.classList.add("_sending");
  let response = await fetch("sendmail.php", { //ТУТ ОШИБКУ ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ
    method: "POST";
    body: formData
  });
  if (response.ok) {
    //сразу при отправке добавляется класс sending
    let result = await response.json(); //файл sendmail.php будет возвращать JSON ответ, и если в ок, то выполняется функция
    alert(result.message); // алерт об отправке
    formPreview.innerHTML = ""; // чистка div с классом formPreview
    form.reset(); // Очистка всех полей форм
    form.classList.remove("_sending");
  } else {
    alert("Error");
    form.classList.remove("_sending");
  }
} else {
  alert("Fill underlined fields");
}
}
```

Comment: fetch возвращает код ответа сервера. Смотрите логи сервера

Comment: К сожалению, в backend'е полный ноль(

Comment: @Архимед На стороне фронта 500 ошибка значит, что проблемы на сервере. Больше никакой информации Вы не получите. Нужно идти в бэкенд, смотреть по логам, почему ошибка, и разбираться.

Comment: Cпасибо, разобрался. В пробной версии данного хостинга запрещена отправка писем посредством php.Может, подскажете хостинги с пробным периодом, где можно пользоваться PHPMailer?